# Specified or default maximum value for Y-axis in SSRS chart

Tags: reporting-services

I'm trying to create a report in SSRS with a chart whose Y-axis I want to be able to limit to a user-specified value. It is easy to use a report parameter to do this, but I want to allow a value of null to revert to the auto-calculated maximum. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Can't be done as far as I know, in the simple way. You could use some custom code to approximate the auto-calculated maximum, though.

Answer (score 3):

You could calculate the maximum yourself in as expression. eg.

```
=IIf(IsNumeric(Parameters!ChartMax.Value),Parameters!ChartMax.Value,Max(Fields!YValue.Value))
```

You probably want to multiply the max by 1.1 to give you some padding to the top of the graph.

Answer (score 0):

Jim, your idea gave me an idea to try and it worked.

If you just do the if statement, except return a blank value when the parameter is not numeric, SSRS 2005 reverts back to the default.

So, this seems to work:

```
=IIf(IsNumeric(Parameters!ChartMax.Value),Parameters!ChartMax.Value,"")
```